# How to call a URL in Django and get response in Django screen

Tags: django

I have a external URL say (http://127.0.0.1:5000/getCombinations) I need to call this URL in my Django view and get output in Django screen only

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from django.http import HttpResponse
import math

def form(request):
    return render(request,'hello/output.html')
def combination(request):
    n=int(request.POST.get("no"))
    respond= requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/getCombinations')
    return render( request, 'hello/output.html', {'msg': respond['msg']})
```

output.html

```
  <body>
  <form action="combination" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}

  Enter number: <br/>
  <input type="number" name="no"> <br/>

  <input type="submit" ><br/>

  </form>
```

URL method

```
  from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
  from flask_restful import Api, Resource
  import math
  from itertools import combinations

  app = Flask(__name__)

  @app.route('/getCombinations',methods=['POST'])
  def getCombinations():
      data=request.get_json()
      n=data['n']
      a=[]
      r=[]
      d=[]
      b=int(n)
      c=int(n)+1
      for i in range(c):
         r.append(i)
         com=math.factorial(b)/(math.factorial(r[i])*math.factorial(b-r[i]))
         a.append(com)
     for i in enumerate(a):
         d.append(i)
     return jsonify({'out':d})
```

My requirement is to call the URL into my Django view and get output correspond to it in Django screen. When I am using above code I am getting error I don't get the correct code to call/invoke that URL in my Django screen

Comment: what does `getCombinations` return?

Comment: You question is really chaotic and imprecise please correct it so we can somehow help you. Give more info and specify the question proprely

Comment: getcombinations is a function which I created based on combination method. I wiil give code for that URL also